# iPhone Footer like functionality

Tags: iphone, uiview, controls, uiviewcontroller

I am having trouble with designing my App.
I am having a button and a label in every page, required functionality is when user clicks a button, it will fetch the last tweet of application's tweeter account and will display it in label.
I know how to fetch and display it in one page.
My question is, can't I create something like custom control, which i just need to place in every page.

Hope, i was able to explain my question.
Any help will be appreciated.. thanks in advance.

Paresh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you create this footer view and place it in the first view (or a base view) and add all the subsequent views below it.. or you could even add it directly to the window..